# Write Access Violation (@ 0xCDCDCDCD) When Pushing Values To Front Of Queue (Linked List)

Tags: c

I am not sure why, but when the code gets to `queue->tail->next = newLink;` in

```
void listQueueAddBack (struct Queue* queue, TYPE value) {
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (queue != 0);
    struct Link* newLink = (struct Link*) malloc (sizeof (struct Link));
    assert (newLink != NULL);
    newLink->value = value;
    queue->tail->next = newLink;
    queue->tail = newLink;
}
```

I get a write access violation (address 0xCDCDCDCD). Did I accidentally pass a null pointer? I'm still a bit new to C, so this is a learning experience for me.

I also tinkered with the `listQueueIsEmpty`, as it had a read access violation, but I seem to have gotten past that. Now I am at the actual push part.

I'm not sure if this is too much, but I don't really know much about what is causing it, so here is all the useful bits of the code file. I don't want others to do my homework for me, but if there are any super big code errors, please do let me know as it helps me learn when dealing with future C projects. I tried to collapse this a bit so no one has to do the 100 meter scroll to get to the bottom (it's not too long, but still)

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef TYPE
#define TYPE int
#endif

// Single link
struct Link {
    TYPE value;
    struct Link* next;
};

// Single linked list with head and tail pointers
struct Queue {
    struct Link* head;
    struct Link* tail;
};

// Stack with two Queue instances
struct Stack {
    struct Queue* q1;
    struct Queue* q2;
};

/**
    Internal func allocates the queue's sentinel. Sets sentinels' next to null,
    and queue's head and tail to the sentinel.
    param:  queue   struct LinkedList ptr
    pre:    queue is not null
    post:   queue sentinel not null
            sentinel next points to null
            head points to sentinel (always)
            tail points to sentinel (always point to last link unless empty)
 */
void listQueueInit(struct Queue* queue) 
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert(queue != 0);

    struct Link* sentinel = (struct Link*)malloc (sizeof (struct Link));
    assert (sentinel != 0);

    sentinel->next = 0;
    queue->head = sentinel;
    queue->tail = sentinel;
}

/**
    Allocates and initializes a queue.
    pre:    none
    post:   memory allocated for new struct Queue ptr
            queue init (call to _initQueue func)
    return: queue
 */
struct Queue* listQueueCreate() 
{

     /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    struct Queue* queue = (struct Queue*) malloc (sizeof (struct Queue));
    listQueueInit (queue);
    return queue;
}

/**
    Adds a new link with the given value to the back of the queue.
    param:  queue   struct Queue ptr
    param:  value   TYPE
    pre:    queue is not null
    post:   link is created with given value 
            link is added after the current last link (pointed to by queue tail)
 */

void listQueueAddBack (struct Queue* queue, TYPE value) 
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (queue != NULL);
    assert (queue->tail != NULL);
    struct Link* newLink = (struct Link*) malloc (sizeof (struct Link));
    assert (newLink != NULL);
    newLink->value = value;
    newLink->next = NULL;
    queue->tail->next = newLink;
    queue->tail = newLink;
}

/**
    Returns the value of the link at the front of the queue.
    param:  queue   struct Queue ptr
    pre:    queue is not null
    pre:    queue is not empty (i.e., queue's head next pointer is not null)
    post:   none
    ret:    first link's value 
 */
TYPE listQueueFront(struct Queue* queue) 
{

   /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (queue != NULL);
    assert (listQueueIsEmpty(queue) != 1);
    return ((queue->head)->next)->value;
}

/**
    Removes the link at the front of the queue and returns the value
    of the removed link.
    param:  queue   struct Queue ptr
    pre:    queue is not null
    pre:    queue is not empty (i.e., queue's head next pointer is not null)
    post:   first link is removed and freed (call to removeLink)
 */
int listQueueIsEmpty (struct Queue* queue);
TYPE listQueueRemoveFront(struct Queue* queue) 
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (queue != 0);
    assert (!listQueueIsEmpty(queue));
    struct Link* toDelete = queue->head->next;
    if (toDelete == queue->tail) {
        queue->tail = queue->head;
    }
    else {
        queue->head->next = toDelete->next;
    }
    return toDelete;
    free (toDelete);
}

/**
    Returns 1 if the queue is empty and 0 otherwise.
    param:  queue   struct Queue ptr
    pre:    queue is not null
    post:   none
    ret:    1 if queue head next pointer is null (empty); 
            otherwise 0 (not null; not empty)
 */
int listQueueIsEmpty(struct Queue* queue) 
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (queue != NULL);
    assert (queue->tail != NULL);
    if ((queue->head)->next == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
    Deallocates every link in the queue including the sentinel,
    and frees the queue itself.
    param:  queue   struct Queue ptr
    pre:    queue is not null
    post:   memory allocated to each link is freed
            " " sentinel " "
            " " queue " "
 */
void listQueueDestroy(struct Queue* queue) 
{

        assert(queue != NULL);
    while(!listQueueIsEmpty(queue)) {
        listQueueRemoveFront(queue);
    }
    free(queue->head);
    free(queue);
    queue = NULL;

}

/**
    Allocates and initializes a stack that is comprised of two 
    instances of Queue data structures.
    pre:    none
    post:   memory allocated for new struct Stack ptr
            stack q1 Queue instance init (call to queueCreate func)
            stack q2 Queue instance init (call to queueCreate func)
    return: stack
 */
struct Stack* listStackFromQueuesCreate() 
{
     /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc (sizeof (struct Stack));
    stack->q1 = listQueueCreate();
    stack->q2 = listQueueCreate();
    return (stack);
};

/**
    Deallocates every link in both queues contained in the stack,
    (inc.the sentinel), the queues themselves and the stack itself.
    param:  stack   struct Stack ptr
    pre:    stack is not null
    pre:    queues are not null
    post:   memory allocated to each link is freed along with the 
            two queues and stack themselves

    Note that I checked that q1 and q2 are not null in this function
    also when I could have just left the assertion to fail in queueDestroy
    if either were pointing to null, but I thought it best to be explicit,
    albeit slightly repetitive.
 */
void listStackDestroy(struct Stack* stack)
{
    assert(stack != NULL);
    assert(stack->q1 != NULL && stack->q2 != NULL);
    listQueueDestroy(stack->q1);
    listQueueDestroy(stack->q2);
    free(stack);
    stack = NULL;
}

/**
    Returns 1 if the stack is empty and 0 otherwise.
    param:  stack   struct Stack ptr
    pre:    stack is not null
    post:   none
    ret:    1 if q1 is empty; else, 0
 */
int listStackIsEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{

    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (stack != NULL);
    if (listQueueIsEmpty (stack->q1)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
    This internal function swaps what q1 and q2 pointers, such that
    q1 points to q2 and q2 points to q1.
    param:  stack   struct LinkedList ptr
    param:  value   TYPE
    pre:    stack is not null
    post:   q1 points to the actual 'stack' with links
 */
void listSwapStackQueues(struct Stack* stack)
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (stack != 0);
    struct Queue* temp = stack->q1;
    stack->q1 = stack->q2;
    stack->q2 = temp;
}

/**
    Adds a new link with the given value to the back of the Queue q2.
    Then while Queue q1 isn't empty, the first link of the queue is 
    dequeued/removed and added to the back of Queue q2, so that in
    the end, Queue q2 has the new order to represent the stack properly
    with the new value at the front of the queue.
    param:  stack   struct LinkedList ptr
    param:  value   TYPE
    pre:    stack is not null
    post:   new link is created w/ given value and added to end of q2
            the first link of q1 is removed and added to end of q2 until
            it's empty
            q1 and q2 are swapped
 */
void listStackPush(struct Stack* stack, TYPE value) 
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (stack != NULL);
    listQueueAddBack (stack->q2, value);
    while (!listQueueIsEmpty(stack->q1))
    {
        TYPE valueTemp = listQueueRemoveFront (stack->q1);
        listQueueAddBack (stack->q2, valueTemp);
    }
    listSwapStackQueues (stack);
}

/**
    Removes the link at the top of the stack and returns its value.
    param:  stack   struct Stack ptr
    pre:    stack is not null
    pre:    stack is not empty
    post:   first link is removed and freed (call to removeLink)
    ret:    value of the removed link
 */
TYPE listStackPop(struct Stack* stack) 
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (stack != 0);
    assert (!listQueueIsEmpty (stack->q1));
    return listQueueRemoveFront (stack->q1);
}

/**
    Returns the value of the link at the top of the stack.
    param:  stack   struct Stack ptr
    pre:    stack is not null
    pre:    stack is not empty
    post:   none
    ret:    first link's value 
 */
TYPE listStackTop(struct Stack* stack) 
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (!listQueueIsEmpty (stack->q1));
    assert (stack != 0);
    return listQueueFront (stack->q1);
}

/**
    Used for testing the stack from queue implementation.
 */

void assertTrue(int pred, char* msg) 
{
    printf("%s: ", msg);
    if(pred)
        printf("\tPASSED\n");
    else
        printf("\tFAILED\n");
}

int main() 
{
    struct Stack* s = listStackFromQueuesCreate();
    assert(s);
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------------\n"); 
    printf("---- Testing stack from queue implementation ----\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n"); 
    printf("stack init...\n");
    assertTrue(listStackIsEmpty(s) == 1, "stackIsEmpty == 1");

    printf("\npushing 4, 5, -300...\n");
    listStackPush(s, 4);
    listStackPush(s, 5);
    listStackPush(s, -300);

    assertTrue(listStackIsEmpty(s) == 0, "stackIsEmpty == 0");
    assertTrue(listStackPop(s) == -300, "\npopping; val == -300");
    assertTrue(listStackPop(s) == 5, "popping; val == 5");
    assertTrue(listStackTop(s) == 4, "top val == 4\t");
    assertTrue(listStackPop(s) == 4, "popping; val == 4");
    assertTrue(listStackIsEmpty(s) == 1, "stackIsEmpty == 1");
    // listStackPop(s);     // should fail assert
    // listStackTop(s);     // should fail assert

    printf("\npushing 0-9...\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        listStackPush(s, i);
    }
    assertTrue(listStackTop(s) == 9, "top val == 9\t");

    listStackDestroy(s);

    return 0;
}
```

~-~-~-Edit 1-~-~-~

Updated code thing above, should have return now.

Also, I currently use Visual Studio 2019 for my compiler. My university has a Unix compiler, but I haven't tested it yet because of having to VPN into it first and what not. I will eventually test it, I just didn't as of doing this code.

~-~-~-Edit 2-~-~-~
added code edits again (this time with return derp fixed)

sorry for the amount of errors, I just now got back into C coding since I had to take some classes in junior college in a really weird order, mostly due to availability of classes, since my data structures normally wouldn't be available until fall of next year. I just happened to get lucky and transfer to Uni and got into it there

Comment: `queue != NULL` instead of `queue != 0` and check `queue->tail != NULL`

Comment: please note that `assert` in most case only work if your code has been compile with the debug flag, without it `assert` generate no code ( see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html ), I would recommend adding some additional code to deal with compilation without the debug flag

Comment: The code you gave doesn't compile for me.

Comment: Hint: google `0xCDCDCDCD`.

Comment: Other hint: compile with all warnings enabled and treat warning as errors. `listQueueRemoveFront` doesn't return anything. And you use `listQueueIsEmpty` without it being defined.

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2019 to compile, it worked up until the part where it crashes. Assert worked fine for me so far, and the instructor included a few other assert statements that worked (other questions, already done).

Also, thanks for catching the lack of return on that function, I guess I must have deleted the return in the mayhem of trying to fix my bugs

Comment: Did changes suggested as far as the checks, sadly, nothing :/

Same error comes back up. The only other thing VS tells me is a warning about `stack` in `struct Stack* listStackFromQueuesCreate()`. It was a warning about dereferencing a null pointer, though the code still runs the required init.

For those who this code does not compile for, I found this online compiler to compile the code (it'll still crash in the current state of that code though, but a few of the outputs will still print before that happens) https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: Using assert is fine if you don't expect the condition to *ever* happen and you are surprised if it does. If you expect it to happen, then you should use an if statement to check and handle accordingly.

Comment: Can you update your post with the updated code? If you did any?

Comment: ah... Yeah, I'm just using it because the commented instructions say for me to :/

Comment: Added edit to the code block showing current state of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has more than 1 problem. But your particular problem is being caused by `listSwapStackQueues`.

You are allocating some memory for a temp Queue, then you assign the pointer to that memory to `q2`. Then you use free to deallocate the memory, leaving q2 pointing to something that is no longer there.

In fact, you don't need to allocate any memory here at all, since probably all you want is to swap the pointers. All you need to do in this case is:

```
struct Queue *temp = stack->q1;    
stack->q1 = stack->q2;
stack->q2 = temp;
```

Are you using a debugger to debug your program? If you don't, you should familiarize yourself with one. Finding memory errors like these can be difficult without a proper debugger.

You will run into more issues like these, so having a good debugger is important. If you are on Windows, I would recommend just getting Visual Studio, since it is free and pretty powerful.

EDIT:

Next to the answers given by the others, there is also the following:
When you add new nodes to the list, initialize next as NULL. i.e., in your function `listQueueAddBack`:

```
    struct Link* newLink = (struct Link*) malloc (sizeof (struct Link));
    assert (newLink != NULL);
    newLink->value = value;
    // Initialize next. 
    newLink->next = NULL;
```

Comment: I actually do use visual studio :P

Just made an edit on the main question saying that, I should have been more clear about that from the beginning

Also, thanks for the suggestion about pointer swap, I was actually curious about that, so I just did the first thing that came to mind. I guess I was just over thinking it again (not surprising)

Comment: Did changing this change anything about the error or where it happens?

Comment: Could that sentinel be causing issues? I am still trying to understand how it interacts with the head and tail nodes. And no, sadly none of the edits changed a thing. As soon as a call is made to the first add to front command, it goes to the write access violation.

I've always been using VS, though I only just recently went from 2017 version to the latest (2019)

Comment: Still your previous code was incorrect. Hopefully you understand why it was.

Comment: Not sure why this code compiles for you under VS. It really should not with a missing return value and mismatching types.

Comment: I'm just as curious as you are, normally VS screams about it, but not that time for some reason, so I totally forgot about it after I accidentally removed it. And uhhh... sorry, I really am a rookie when it comes to the whole coding thing... I also kinda didn't do any C coding for about 6 months because of the order I had to take some classes back in junior college, so that also kinda kicked me real hard right in the butt. I learn by example, so sometimes I need to see a completed program (or several for that matter), in order for me to understand different situations, like pointer swaps, etc.

Comment: Well dang, guess that one lack of initialization is what sent that whole read/write thing, thanks! Now time for me to go skitter off into my little corner again and figure out the rest of the stack bugs... Everything compiles now (for now at least).

Answer (score 0):

1. There is one problem in swapping queues:

   void listSwapStackQueues(struct Stack* stack)
   {
       /* FIXME: You will write this function */
       assert (stack != 0);
       struct Queue* temp = (struct Queue*) malloc (sizeof(struct Queue));
       temp = stack->q1;
       stack->q1 = stack->q2;
       stack->q2 = temp;
       free (temp);
   }

This is freeing the `stack->q1` pointer, so invalidating list head and straight up leaks memory. Doing:

```
type *pnt = malloc(...); 
pnt = ...
```

is always wrong and leaks memory. Just swap the pointers, without doing any malloc and free:

```
void listSwapStackQueues(struct Stack* stack)
{
    assert (stack != 0);
    struct Queue* temp;
    temp = stack->q1;
    stack->q1 = stack->q2;
    stack->q2 = temp;
}
```

2. The type of pointer passed to `listQueueIsEmpty` inside `listQueueRemoveFront` inside assertion is invalid:

   TYPE listQueueRemoveFront(struct Queue* queue)
   {
       assert (listQueueIsEmpty(queue->head)); // invalid

You want to pass the queue, ie. `listQueueIsEmpty(queue)`, to the function. Also list queue should *not* be empty when removing, so you want to probably negate the expression:

```
TYPE listQueueRemoveFront(struct Queue* queue)
{
    assert (!listQueueIsEmpty(queue));
```

Also remember to forward declare the function, so that compiler can warn you:

```
int listQueueIsEmpty(struct Queue* queue);
TYPE listQueueRemoveFront(struct Queue* queue)
{
    assert (!listQueueIsEmpty(queue));
```

3. There is no `return` statement in your `listQueueRemoveFront` function. The code is thus invalid and invokes undefined behavior:

   TYPE listQueueRemoveFront(struct Queue* queue)
   {
       // no return here
   }

   .. later in Push ... 
       TYPE valueTemp = listQueueRemoveFront (stack->q1);

Remember to always compile with warnings enabled (with `gcc` use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`) and to fix all warnings. When compiling with warnings enabled the issue is made clear by the compiler:

```
1.c: In function ‘listQueueFront’:
1.c:98:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘listQueueIsEmpty’; did you mean ‘listQueueInit’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     assert (listQueueIsEmpty(queue) != 1);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1.c: In function ‘listQueueRemoveFront’:
1.c:123:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

Comment: Added a return now, will update again. Thanks for the pointer swap suggestion too, I just put that in! I was a bit curious how the whole swap thing would go for structs, so I thought to do the memory allocation (probably because of something else totally irrelevant).